# Input type="number" using .includes() is false when looking for decimal

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to get a true/false using .includes(".") on an input type of number.

In my snippet I am always getting that the value is always false in looking to see if the value does NOT have a decimal.  Meaning a number like "2" AND "2." are bring back the same result. When the "2." should fall into the ELSE because it does contain a decimal.

If I turn the input type to "text" all works as expected, but when I turn the type into a number, the .includes(".") does not see the input value as having a decimal.

Should be simple, but I have not been able to get past it. I like using the "number" input for built in browser limitations of number only input.

So I have something like this:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("numberBox");
$('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
$(e).on("keyup", function(){
var newValue = this.value;
   checkIt(newValue);
});



function checkIt(newValue){

if(newValue >= 1 && !newValue.includes(".")){

  //if entering "2." this should not fire, but does if input type is number.
       $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', false);
     console.log("TRUE: value does not include a decimal. Value is:" + newValue + ", value type is: " + typeof newValue);
  }else{
  $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', true);
  console.log("FALSE: value includes a decimal. Value is: " + newValue + ", value type is: " + typeof newValue);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="numberBox" value=""/>
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Did you try logging `newValue`? It's `2` for an input of either `"2"` or `"2."`. Likely because the number input itself doesn't allow `"2."` as it's not a valid numeric.

Comment: Did you debug it and see what is returned? `console.log(newValue)`

Comment: *In my snippet I am always getting that the value is always false in looking to see if the value does NOT have a decimal.* <-- Funny, because when I run your code I get `TRUE` when I have NOT entered a decimal and `FALSE` when I have.

Comment: The 'typeof' is bringing back a string.  Which would lead me to using the . includes() would work, but I am now thinking, and I should probably look at Chrome's docs, that Chrome is possibly applying a float method to round the number.  The reason I am doing this is because I don't want users entering a partial number like '2.' instead of a '2.0' or '2.1'.

Comment: Well, first up don't use `keyup` because it will validate upon each keystroke and you can't get to 2.1 without typing the invalid `2.` first, so do you check on the `change` event, which fires when the field loses focus and its value has been changed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, Yes I know this. I also have a submit button that enabled and disabled based on the input.  I don't want to do the change because of this.  My goal  is to validate as they are typing, without a plugin, so that I can enable and disable a submit button (I know not in the code and can update and will update my question.

Comment: @VLAZ, the typeof comes out as string though. Which is why I was under the impression that the .includes() method would work, because it is inheritly implemented to compare the contents of a string.  There must be something on the number input type that is overwriting the .includes() when a single number and a decimal is entered vs when the input is a type of 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you'll face with `input type="number"` is that it only allows valid numbers, so if the user were to enter `2.`, which you and I know is invalid, the control would see that as just `2` which is valid. **`includes` would never pick up the `.`.**

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(){
   console.log(this.value);  // 2 not 2.1
});
```

```html
Type 2. and watch the console output <input type="number">
```

**To get the behavior you want, you'll need to use a regular text input, and check for bad characters on `keydown` and validate the input on `keyup`.**

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){
  // prevent non-numeric chars, but allow BACKSPACE and DELETE
  let nums = /^\d+|\./g;
  let valid = nums.test(evt.key);
  
  // If the input is not valid, backspace, delete or the left/right arrow keys....
  if(!valid && evt.code != "Backspace" && evt.code != "Delete" && 
         evt.code != "ArrowLeft" && evt.code != "ArrowRight"){
      evt.preventDefault();
  }
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
  let reg = /^(-?\d+\.\d+)$|^(-?\d+)$/gm; // RegExp to test for valid nummber
  let valid = reg.test(input.value);      // Test the input
  input.setCustomValidity(valid ? "" : "Invalid!"); // Set validity    
});
```

```css
input:invalid { border:2px solid red; }
input:valid { border:2px solid green; }
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: this was going to be my next approach.  Thanks for the regex example   Seems that even if the input type of Number is 'typeof' is outputting as a string, the browser must be rounding or messing with the passing of the value to the JS.  I will mark yours as  solution for now, was trhing to have the browser be smart about it and use the number type, but I guess goodl ol' RegEx comes to the rescue again.

Comment: The only issue with this is it would involve a hell of a lot more work just to consistently validate that the user is inputing a digit

Comment: @ClosDesign There is only one data type in HTML - - string. That's what the "T" in HTML stands for. The `input type=number` doesn't mean data type, it means input type and it ensures that the field will only ever hold a TEXT value that could be a valid number.

Comment: @alex067 The code currently does just that with a simple regex check on `keydown`.

Comment: @alex067,  I saw you answer below, but do you have any code examples of what you might be thinking about?

Answer (score -2):

You could take your input from your DOM, convert it to a string, perform the decimal includes comparison, and convert it back to a float or integer depending on the results of the comparison.

EDIT:
Understood the question clearly.

Comment: My issue is I don't want to give users the ability to enter alpha characters, hence why I am using the number input.  My question pertains to looking at if the entered number has a trailing decimal after the initial number.

Comment: Ah okay I see. 

You can just convert your input, from your input number, to a string, use includes, and convert it back to a float or int depending on if there is a decimal number.

Comment: yes, more or less. I updated my question because I have a submit button that I want to enable and disable as the user is entering the number.  Mainly giving the user feedback prior to pushing the submit button.